# What's the proper syntax for Java's BigDecimal?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have two `double` counters that I'm incrementing based on certain criteria. The counters will increment by either 1 or .01, and the results summed together for a serial number of `1.00`, `1.01`, `1.02`, etc. I'm getting results like `1.01999999999` or `1.111111111111`, an expected condition due to the nature of `double`.

I am trying to use BigDecimal, and although the [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) indicates

```
BigDecimal(double val)
           Translates a double into a BigDecimal which is the exact decimal representation of the double's binary floating-point value.
```

I cannot get the code to work.

```
            ....
if (condition1) {
    indexNo = indexNo + 1;
    subIndexNo = .00;
} else
    if (condition2) {
        subIndexNo = subIndexNo + .01;
    }
recNo = indexNo + subIndexNo;
BigDecimal record = BigDecimal(double recNo);
```

Error messages from the compiler

```
C:\pathtojava\sync\java\bin>javac ParseWhiData.java
ParseWhiData.java:97: error: '.class' expected
                                BigDecimal record = BigDecimal(double recNo);
                                                                      ^
ParseWhiData.java:97: error: ';' expected
                                BigDecimal record = BigDecimal(double recNo);
                                                                           ^
2 errors
```

What am I doing wrong while accessing BigDecimal? What's the proper syntax to convert a double to a Big Demimal, and, most importantly, will it turn `1.019999999999` to `1.02`

Comment: Looks like you need to review the basics of Java OOP.

Comment: Maybe you could just use an integer and increment it by 1 or 100. Integers are made for counting ;)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - I'm an old procedural hack from days gone by just getting started with OO. I frequently forget that what looks like a method can sometimes be creating a new object...it's a process. :)

Comment: Yes, I understand it is a process. My comment intention wasn't to feel bad about this but to read again about Java OOP concepts where it is covered how to create a new instance of the class. Note that this problem could have happened with another class as well :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BigDecimal (and every object in Java) is instantiated via the `new` operator.

Also, get rid of the `double` keyword in the constructor, since you already have defined a variable named `recNo`.

Change

```
BigDecimal record = BigDecimal(double recNo);
```

to

```
BigDecimal record = new BigDecimal(recNo);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the other constructor [`BigDecimal(String val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) to get the exact precision:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("4.81");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("0.01");
BigDecimal c = a.add(b);
System.out.println(c);

BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(4.81);
BigDecimal e = new BigDecimal(0.01);
BigDecimal f = d.add(e);
System.out.println(f);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
4.82
4.81999999999999960940966214906211462221108376979827880859375
```